# What is the nomenclature to connect to a SQL Server Express 2014 database?

Tags: oledbconnection

I am connecting to an Access 2007 database:

```
oleConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\...\\Db.accdb");
```

What is the nomenclature to connect to an SQL Server Express 2014 database?

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString =
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1" + ";" +
    "Integrated Security=SSPI" + ";" + //Windows authentication
    "Persist Security Info=False" + ";" +
    "User Instance=True" + ";" +
    "Data Source=CTE-LAPTOP\\SQLEXPRESS" + ";" +
    "Initial Catalog=SqlServerDbExample" + ";" + //Database name
    "AttachDBFilename=C:\\..\\SqlServerDbExample.mdf" + ""; //Filename

OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
```